# getting Error while constructing parser using argparse.ArgumentParser()

Tags: python, python-3.x, argparse

I am doing data extraction from scanned document.I am using the below code for constructing and parsing the arguments:

```
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract
import argparse
import cv2
import os
import re
import io
import json
import ftfy

ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-i", "--image", required=True,
                help="path to input image to be OCR'd")
ap.add_argument("-p", "--preprocess", type=str, default="thresh",
                help="type of preprocessing to be done, choose from blur, linear, cubic or bilateral")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())
```

The line `args = vars(ap.parse_args())` is throwing an error as below:

```
usage: [-h] -i IMAGE [-p PREPROCESS]
: error: the following arguments are required: -i/--image
An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.

SystemExit: 2

C:\Users\Aditya\anaconda\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py:3339: UserWarning: To exit: use 'exit', 'quit', or Ctrl-D.
  warn("To exit: use 'exit', 'quit', or Ctrl-D.", stacklevel=1)
```

As I am new on working with images, so need help to solve this error.

Comment: how are yoy calling this script?  You need to provide command line arguments. Is this a `ipython` console?

Comment: The `ipyhon` help shows: `ipython [subcommand] [options] [-c cmd | -m mod | file] [--] [arg] ...`   The arguments for your `argparse` are those `[arg]` after the `--`.  If instead you are running this in a `jupyter` notebook, you can't use `argparse`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parse the args like this:
`args = ap.parse_args()`, and you must give `--image` or `-i` parameter when launching the script (because you have `required=True`)